# Selenium creating bulk email addresses

Tags: selenium, email

I want to use selenium to create several email addresses at once. I suppose they can be random but I already have a list of the email account names I want to create.

I know how to create 1 email using webdriver but how would I go about it if I want to sign up several, one after the other automatically, without having to always change the code?

Simple code for creating 1 email:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://hotmail.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/C:Users/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'linkButtonSigninHeader')]/@href").click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_id('MemberName').send_keys('usernameexample')
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_id('iSignupAction).click()
time.sleet(2)

driver.find_element_by_id('PasswordInput').send_keys('Passwordexample1')
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_id('iSignupAction').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_id('FirstName').send_keys('john')
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_id('LastName').send_keys('wayne')
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_id('iSignupAction').click()
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Comment: If you can create one than run your code in loop, again agree with @RyanWilson share your code for better answer.

Comment: I would recommend you to post a code here + I would store it in a file and then parse it, by itteratin though this file :)

Comment: Posted what I have. Very new to selenium but this basic code worked okay.

Comment: Not sure why getting downvoted here. I'm new to this forum so if I should change anything in my post I would be happy to.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. You're probably getting downvotes because you haven't posted the code that you're written to solve your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you could iterate over a data collection, such as an array:

```
array_of_usernames = ['username_one', 'username_two']

array_of_usernames.each do |username|

  url = 'https://hotmail.com/'

  driver = webdriver.Chrome('/C:Users/Desktop/chromedriver')
  driver.get(url)

  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'linkButtonSigninHeader')]/@href").click()
  driver.find_element_by_id('MemberName').send_keys("#{username}")  #INTERPOLATED BLOCK-LOCAL VARIABLE HERE
  driver.find_element_by_id('iSignupAction).click()
  driver.find_element_by_id('PasswordInput').send_keys('Passwordexample1')
  driver.find_element_by_id('iSignupAction').click()
  driver.find_element_by_id('FirstName').send_keys('john')
  driver.find_element_by_id('LastName').send_keys('wayne')
  driver.find_element_by_id('iSignupAction').click()

  # some step to log out so that next username can register

end
```

If you aren't familiar with arrays or iteration, then I'd suggest looking at the docs to get your head around it: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-each

Comment: Thank you so much! All I wanted was a bit of advice on what would be the best way to go about something like this and this is a huge help. Wish I could upvote your comment!

Comment: Glad it helped.  If it solved your issue, you can accept the answer.  Good luck!